# Problem with jqGrid in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have developed an ASP.NET MVC (version 2 RC) application with a ton of jqGrids.  It's working like a champ in Firefox, but I've discovered a problem in IE8.

The "Main View" grids can be filtered by a search box or one of a few dropdowns above the grid.  I use some javascript to reset the url for the grid, then trigger a reload, thusly:

```
function filterByName(filter) {
        if (filter == 'All') {
            $('#list').setGridParam({ url: 'Application/GetApplications' });
            $('#list').trigger("reloadGrid");
        }
        else {
            $('#list').setGridParam({ url: 'Application/GetAppByName/' + filter + '/' });
            $('#list').trigger("reloadGrid");
        }
    }
```

This works like magic in Firefox, but I'm getting an HTTP 400 Bad Request when I do this in IE8.  The IE8 client-side debugger is like flint and tinder compared to Firebug's flamethrower, so I'm not having much luck figuring out why it breaks in IE8.  Has anyone seen this?

Also, the jqGrid "trigger" method here is swallowing the AJAX exception.  Is there a way to get it to bubble up so I can get to the exception details?

**UPDATE**:

The problem was with the syntax in my "onchange" event for the dropdowns.  I was using:

```
onchange="filterByMnemonic($('#drpMnemonic')[0].value);
```

Which Firefox apparently doesn't mind but IE sees that as nuthin'.  This, however, works in both browsers:

```
onchange = "filterByMnemonic($('#drpMnemonic > option:selected').attr('value'));"
```

Comment: Use Fiddler with IE. `trigger` *will not* swallow the 400 response (which is *not* an exception!). But if you don't handle them (e.g., with the `ajaxError` event), you won't ever see them.

Comment: Also: jqGrid in general and `setGridParam` / `url` in particular work fine in IE8. We use this extensively. Your problem is most likely the request itself. Fiddler will help with that.

Comment: Craig, you da man.  See update for details.

Comment: I guess $('#drpMnemonic').val() will also work and is the std way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

The problem was with the syntax in my "onchange" event for the dropdowns. I was using:

```
onchange="filterByMnemonic($('#drpMnemonic')[0].value);
```

Which Firefox apparently doesn't mind but IE sees that as nuthin'. This, however, works in both browsers:

```
onchange = "filterByMnemonic($('#drpMnemonic > option:selected').attr('value'));"
```